# Pegar valor e data attr de elemento relacionado jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Estou com um pequeno problema com jQuery, tenho a seguinte ordem de divs:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.btn_salvar_obg_acess_prazo', function() {
  var data = $(this).prev('.acess_prazo_date').val();
  alert(data);
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <span><?php echo $obrigacao_correspondente_nome ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" data-m='<?php echo $m_c ?>' data-a='<?php echo $a_c ?>' data-obg='<?php echo $obrigacao_correspondente ?>' value="<?php echo $data ?>" name="obg_acess_prazo" class="acess_prazo_date datepicker_full form-control">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn_salvar_obg_acess_prazo">Salvar</button>
      <hr>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Essas rows são geradas através de um consulta no mysql, e pode haver mais de uma, eu preciso que quando clique no botão 'Salvar' ele pegue o valor dos atributos data-[] e o valor do input anterior.

Ja tentei com '.find()', '.parent()', '.prev()' e ainda não consegui, sempre resulta em 'undefined'.

Comment: Poste a saída html completa, sem php. Por favor!

Comment: Só há 1 input por cada `.row`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testa usar

```
var data = $(this).closest('div').prev().find('.acess_prazo_date').val();
```

caso haja vários inputs em cada `.row`, ou caso haja só 1:

```
var data = $(this).closest('.row').find('.acess_prazo_date').val();
```

### Explicação:

**Primeira variante:**

Sobe no DOM até ao `div`, (neste caso poderia ser somente `.parent()`, mas assim fica à prova de mudanças futuras) depois procura o elemento anterior (entre os irmãos/siblings) e por fim desce no DOM à procura de `.acess_prazo_date`.

**Segunda variante:**

Com o `.closest('.row')` ele pega diretamente elemento com a classe `.row` mais próximo, e depois com `.find('.acess_prazo_date')` ele procura dentro desse elemento o elemento com a classe `.acess_prazo_date`.

O `.val()` devolve o `value` do input.

Comment: Eu consegui com 
 var data = $(this).parent('div').parent('div').find('.acess_prazo_date').val();

Mas a segunda opção que você deu funcionou, e com menos ações, valeu!